# Transfer files through WIFI Android

Tags: android, file, wifi, transfer

I'm in the middle of an android app that need to check whether the device is connected to a pc via wifi and if it is connected i need to send a copy of my database file through through wifi. I have no idea how to do this. Do i have to create a server app at pc??

pls help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "the device is connected to a pc via wifi" mean exactly? Connected how? Describe your problem better please.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean that device is in the same network with known PC.
if so when you can use existing server side application for your PC: samba (windows shared folder) or ftp server. when you don't need to create code for PC only for device.